# SwiftUI: Align a View to the center of its Parent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an array of items that I'm displaying in a SwiftUI List like so:

```swift
struct MissionCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var missions: [Mission] = [
        Mission(name: "Cassini",
                launchDate: "10/15/97",
                launchLocation: "Cape Canaveral",
                missionEndDate: "09/15/17",
                status: "Past"),
        Mission(name: "Galaxy Evolution Explorer",
                launchDate: "04/28/03",
                launchLocation: "Cape Canaveral",
                missionEndDate: "06/28/13",
                status: "Past"),
        Mission(name: "IRAS",
                launchDate: "01/25/83",
                launchLocation: "Vandenberg",
                missionEndDate: "11/21/83",
                status: nil),
        Mission(name: "NuSTAR",
                launchDate: "06/13/12",
                launchLocation: "Central Pacific Ocean",
                missionEndDate: nil,
                status: "Current"),
        Mission(name: "Voyager 1",
                launchDate: "09/05/77",
                launchLocation: "Central Pacific Ocean",
                missionEndDate: nil,
                status: nil)
    ]

    static var previews: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(missions) { mission in
                MissionCell(mission: mission)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm creating a cell View with the following code:

```swift
struct MissionCell: View {
    var mission: Mission

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .missionOptionalInfoAlignment, spacing: 2) {
            Text(mission.name)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .truncationMode(.middle)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "calendar")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                        Text(mission.launchDate)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                        Text(mission.launchLocation)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                    }

                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    if mission.missionEndDate != nil {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "hand.raised.slash.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                            Text(mission.missionEndDate!)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                        }
                    }
                    if mission.status != nil {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                            Text(mission.status ?? "")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
    }
}
```

There are 2 alignments that I'm trying to achieve:

1. Alignment of the `missionEndDate` and `status` values. I'm successfully achieving this using Stack alignments.
2. **Alignment of the `HStack` that displays the `missionEndDate` and `status` values to the center of the `MissionCell` View. I can NOT achieve this.** I tried using custom alignments, but I can't do it with custom alignments because there's nothing to align this `HStack` with (i.e. I can't tell it to align to it's parent's center). Here's an image of it currently looks like:
   [image: Image showing incomplete alignment]

I've thought about using `GeometryReader` to get the geometry of the top-level `VStack`, but then I lose all spacing information and can no longer make use of alignments.

Is there a way to align a child view deep in the tree of a custom View, such that it's at the center of it's parent's container?

Comment: I suggest you may consider use ZStack, or overlay.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I'm actually giving overlay a try now, with Anchor Preferences. I'll post an answer if I can get what I'm looking for.

Comment: You could also use `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` to set the width of a column. With this you don't lose all the spacing information. However, if you rotate the device it will not update automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one case with Zstack:

```
  struct  ListMissionView : View{


                    var missions: [Mission] = [
                        Mission(name: "Cassini",
                                launchDate: "10/15/97",
                                launchLocation: "Cape Canaveral",
                                missionEndDate: "09/15/17",
                                status: "Past"),
                        Mission(name: "Galaxy Evolution Explorer",
                                launchDate: "04/28/03",
                                launchLocation: "Cape Canaveral",
                                missionEndDate: "06/28/13",
                                status: "Past"),
                        Mission(name: "IRAS",
                                launchDate: "01/25/83",
                                launchLocation: "Vandenberg",
                                missionEndDate: "11/21/83",
                                status: nil),
                        Mission(name: "NuSTAR",
                                launchDate: "06/13/12",
                                launchLocation: "Central Pacific Ocean",
                                missionEndDate: nil,
                                status: "Current"),
                        Mission(name: "Voyager 1",
                                launchDate: "09/05/77",
                                launchLocation: "Central Pacific Ocean",
                                missionEndDate: nil,
                                status: nil)
                    ]


                        var body: some View {
                            GeometryReader{ proxy in
                      List {
                            ForEach(self.missions, id: \.name) { mission in
                               MissionCell(mission: mission, proxy:  proxy)
                           }
                        }
                       }
                }
                }


            struct MissionCell: View {
                var mission: Mission

                var proxy: GeometryProxy
                var body: some View {

                   // VStack(alignment: .missionOptionalInfoAlignment, spacing: 2) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        Text(self.mission.name)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .truncationMode(.middle)

                        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {

                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                    Text(self.mission.launchDate)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                    Text(self.mission.launchLocation)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                }

                            }

                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                                if self.mission.missionEndDate != nil {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "hand.raised.slash.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                        Text(self.mission.missionEndDate!)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                    }
                                }
                                if self.mission.status != nil {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                        Text(self.mission.status ?? "")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))

                                    }
                                }
                            }.alignmentGuide(.leading){ _ in return -self.proxy.size.width / 2.0}
                        }
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                    }

            }
```

Comment: I hadn't considered using `GeometryReader` on the `List`, that's a good idea. Thanks!